# Why does Nifi PutParquet processor create so many tasks?

Tags: apache-nifi

The Nifi [PutParquet Processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-parquet-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.parquet.PutParquet/index.html) with timer driven run schedule of 0 sec with previous processor in stopped status shows ~3000 Tasks for the last 5 minutes.

[image: Example of the high amount of tasks]

We are on Nifi 1.9.2.

My expectation would be that this processor only creates tasks if data is in the incoming queue for the processor. Is this some misconfiguration or a bug in the implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The processor is annotated with @TriggerWhenEmpty which lets it execute all the time regardless of data in the incoming queue. The reason for this is because in a kerberized environment, the processor needs a chance to refresh the credentials. It was a common problem with other processors where no data comes in for a long time, say over a weekend, and during that time the kerberos ticket expired, and then when data starts coming in Monday everything fails.

These empty executions shouldn't have a big impact on the system. When the processor executes and no data is available, it just calls yield and returns. The default yield duration is 1 second, but is controllable through the UI.

Comment: Thx Bryan, I think the yield duration is 100 ms by default, but as you mentioned it is configurable. Other than that I see the necessity for this behavior. Still it makes our monitoring a bit harder for those flows.

Comment: Yea it may be worth aligning this with PutHDFS since originally they had the same issue, but now the solutions diverged a little bit